# x86 assembly Language - TEST operation and its effect on flags

Tags: assembly, x86, flags

I'm working on an x86 assembly language homework assignment and do not understand how exactly the test operation effects the carry, zero and sign flags. As I understand it, we are doing a bitwise comparison `AND` on two operands. In the first example, bits 1,2,3,4, and 7 match up. Does this mean that the result of the `AND` is 11110010? This would set the sign flag to negative right? Zero flag would not be set because this binary result is not 0. And the carry flag? I'm not really sure how to proceed. Thanks for the help.

```
mov al,00001111b
test al,00000010b ; a. CF= ZF= SF=<br><br>

mov al,00000110b
cmp al,00000101b  ; b. CF= ZF= SF=<br><br>

mov al,00000101b
cmp al,00000111b  ; c. CF= ZF= SF=<br><br>
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEST_(x86_instruction)

Comment: On some other architecture CF isn't necessarily affected by test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you wrote, x86 `TEST` operation does a bitwise `AND` operation. You should check again the truth table for AND:

```
INPUT   OUTPUT
A   B   A AND B
0   0       0
0   1       0
1   0       0
1   1       1
```

`TEST` would do this operation for each 2 corresponding bits in the src and the dst operands, so only bits that are `1` in both would become `1` in the result: `00001111b & 00000010b` would simply give `00000010b`.

The effect on the flags is now simple to see - ZF=0 since the result is non-zero, SF=0 since the result MSB is off, and CF=0 because TEST won't set it (it's a logical operation, not an arithmetic one).

By the way, `TEST` is quite cheap as operations go, so you may notice it's used often as a simple zero check - `TEST RAX, RAX` would AND the RAX register against itself (resulting in the same value of course), so you get a nice way to check if RAX is zero (for e.g. to be used by a `je` branch immediately after), or negative (by using the SF with a `js` branch)

Now, the other 2 questions deal with another operation - `CMP` does an actual subtraction (it's doing the same thing as `SUB`, but also discards the result, only updating the flags).

- The first would compute `00000110b - 00000101b = 00000001b`, with ZF=SF=0 (for the same reasons as above), and CF=0 since we didn't have any need for carry/borrow.
- The second would compute `00000101b - 00000111b = 11111110` (two's complement representation for `5 - 7 = -2`), ZF is still 0 as above, but this time you'd see SF=1 since we got a negative result so the MSB is on, and CF=1 since the calculation did a "borrow" unto the MSB.

There's a bit of a fine point here regarding CF and its counterpart OF (overflow flag) - the numbers are just numbers, they don't mean signed or unsigned values until you decide to use them as such. However x86 has to maintain the correct flags for any possibility, so it basically uses CF for unsigned operations, effectively meaning that the last operation was `5 - 7 = 254` as if you "borrowed" an extra bit to the MSB (and this is what CF=1 marks here). The OF won't get set because if you consider these exact same operation as signed arithmetic, you've really done `5 - 7 = -2` which is perfectly legal and didn't overflow/underflow.

On the other hand, an operation such as `127 + 127 = 254` would do the opposite, it won't switch the CF (because nothing bad happened if you consider this as unsigned arithmetics), but the OF will get set because if these are signed values, you've just said `127 + 127 = -2` which is obviously wrong because there was an overflow past the max signed value a byte can store (127)

Comment: well, in all of these examples, wouldn't all the flags be set to 0? the MSB in each one would be 0 so the SF would be 0 in all 3. In the first example, the result is +2, so no carry or zero flag should be set. In the 2nd example, the result would be 00000100b which is +4, and again, no carry or zero flag. And finally, the 3rd example would be 00000101 which is +5 and no flags would be set. Am I missing something? This seems too simple.

Comment: oh i didn't even notice in the last 2 examples it is a CMP not a TEST

Comment: Sorry, how are the semantics of the sign and carry flags "obvious" from this?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Well, he seems to know how to calculate them fine, he just needed the correct AND operation. He didn't ask us to do the entire exercise for him. Do you think it should be added even though it's a homework question?

Comment: @Leeor: Don't know about the OP, but I know that I personally would welcome a complete explanation when I open a post with this title.

Comment: @KerrekSB, hope that's better